# Gnuplot date/time in x axis

Tags: date, time, gnuplot

I have a quick question regarding dates and times in x-axis in GNUPLOT. I'll let the code do the talking:

This is my data:

```
#Time   Data in Data out
"2013-07-22 15:59:00"   6286    3730
"2013-07-22 15:58:00"   10695   14589
"2013-07-22 15:57:00"   17868   26464
"2013-07-22 15:56:00"   18880   34012
"2013-07-22 15:55:00"   19206   41192
"2013-07-22 15:54:00"   20365   43218
"2013-07-22 15:53:00"   18459   39298
"2013-07-22 15:52:00"   3420    4686
"2013-07-22 15:51:00"   3256    4942
```

And this is the code that is generating the graph:

```
gnuplot> set title "Data usage over the last 24 hours"
gnuplot> unset multiplot
gnuplot> set xdata time
gnuplot> set style data lines  
gnuplot> set term png
Terminal type set to 'png'
Options are 'nocrop font "arial,12" fontscale 1.0 size 640,480 '
gnuplot> set timefmt "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
gnuplot> set format x "%m-%d\n%H:%M"
gnuplot> set xlabel "Time"
gnuplot> set ylabel "Traffic" 
gnuplot> set autoscale y  
gnuplot> set xrange ["2013-07-21 16:00":"2013-07-22 16:00"]
gnuplot> set output "datausage.png"
gnuplot> plot "C:\\Users\\blah\\Desktop\\plot.tmp" using 1:2 t "inbound" w lines, "C:\\Users\\blah\\Desktop\\plot.tmp" u 1:3 t "outbound" w lines
                                                                                                                                                                 ^
         all points y value undefined!
```

Is the problem the space in between `date` and `time` in the x-axis? If not, what do you think could be the problem?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Gnuplot doesn't actually expect time data to be in quotes, so you have to tell it:

```
set timefmt '"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"'
```

You can put the double quotes inside single quotes as I did here, or escape the quotes:

```
set timefmt "\"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S\""
```

the same applies to your `xrange` specification:

```
set xrange ['"2013-07-21 16:00"':'"2013-07-22 16:00"']
```

If you delete the quotes in the data file, then you can use the formatting you originally had, except the column numbers will be shifted over by 1 since the date takes up two columns without the quotes.

Comment: Worth emphasising the first line of this answer: <b>"Gnuplot doesn't actually expect time data to be in quotes, so you have to tell it:"</b>!! Thank you. Gnuplot actually seemed to parse the dates okay but got a really weird range with negative to positive years.

Comment: Also the using 1:2 is not optional.  I got the error "Need full using spec for x time data" if I just used plot "/tmp/foo.gnuplot".

Answer (score 6):

It seems like the answer is yes, the problem was the space.

doing this seems to fix it:

`set datafile separator ","`

and actually separating the times and data with commas.

Comment: This also works.  It seems that when the space is the separator, the quotes are treated as part of the data, so you need to escape them.  When the comma is the separator, gnuplot apparently ignores the quotes.

Comment: well, OP probably doesn't want to change all the data first...

Answer (score 6):

As far as I understood, **the order of instructions** is important, I could afford it using:

- The `timefmt` is for data and has to be the same for xrange
- `format x` is only for displaying

  ```
          set xdata time
          set timefmt "%Y%m%dT%H%M%S"
          set format x "%Y-%m-%d\n%H:%M:%S"
          # or with bash variables: set xrange ["$l_start_dt":"$l_end_dt"]
          set xrange ["20190620T000000":"20190628T000000"]
  ```

Comment: correct! `set xdata time` and `set timefmt ...` have to be **before** `set xrange[ : ]`. But that's the order OP already had. Hence, this is good to know, but not answering OP's question. BTW, gnuplot will tolerate, e.g. `set timefmt "%H:%M:%S"` and missing seconds or even minutes in the data or xrange (it will simply assume `%M` and `%S` to be `0`).

Answer (score -2):

Had to struggle significantly when none of these answers worked because my time series mentioned the months in three letter strings. The table at [GNUplot documentation, {link dead}](http://www.gnuplot.info/docs/loc15502.html) came very handy and hopefully this would save others some hassle.

Something similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21305572/).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: hmmm, certainly well-meant but not really helpful giving an answer to something which was not asked (well, the title is broad, but the question covers a different issue) and additionally giving a dead link (instead, I would suggest `help  time_specifiers`)  and furthermore, giving a link to something which is not really related.  I suggest to delete this answer. It's just more confusing than helpful. Feel free to open a new question with a clear title if you have an issue with the time specifiers (especially `"%b"`, which was not the topic of this question).