# Line is not shown in the diagram using gnuplot

Tags: date, gnuplot

I am trying to plot a diagram using gnuplot. I want to put the hours of the day in the x-axis. I managed to do that with the following code:

```
set term postscript eps enhanced color "Times" 24
set output "DailyAvailability.eps"
set xtics rotate by -45 font ",18"
set xdata time
set timefmt '%Y-%m-%d %H'
set format x '%H:%M'
set ylabel "Number of peers"
set xlabel "Time of the day [in hours]"
set yrange [0:30]
set xrange ['2015-12-30 15:50':'2015-12-30 16:00']
set key right top #FFA500"
plot "intervals.dat" using 1:2 lc rgb "#000077" t "availability" w lines
```

This is my input data

```
"2015-12-30 15:59"  6
"2015-12-30 15:58"  10 
"2015-12-30 15:57"  17
"2015-12-30 15:56"  18
"2015-12-30 15:55"  19
"2015-12-30 15:54"  20 
"2015-12-30 15:53"  18 
"2015-12-30 15:52"  28 
"2015-12-30 15:51"  23
```

After executing the code, I get the diagram but with no line drawn in it. I tried to read other questions, but I cannot see any major differences between their code and mine [Gnuplot date/time in x axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17791828/gnuplot-date-time-in-x-axis). I also checked for blank spaces in the input file, but since there is no error or warning messages, I cannot figure out what is going on. Can anybody see what I am missing here? Thanks for your time!

[image]

Comment: @F.Knorr gives you the real answer, a workaround would be `plot "intervals.dat" using 0:2:xtic( substr( stringcolumn( 1 ), 12, 16 ) ) lc rgb "#000077" t "availability" w lines`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two tiny mistakes that make gnuplot say

> Skipping data file with no valid points

1. Your time format is missing the minutes `%M`. Hence `%H` should be `%H:%M`
2. The quotation marks which are part of your time format are missing.

The solution is supposed to look like this

```
set timefmt '"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"'
```

Then, I get
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot!, that fixed my issue!