# max value for same minute over multiple days from csv with unix timestamps

Tags: gnuplot

I have a CSV with a unix timestamp column that was collected over multiple days having a data row for every 5 minutes (output log of my photo voltaik roof power plant).

I'd like to create a plot for 24 hours that shows the maximum value for every single (fifth) minute  over all days.

Can this be done with `gnuplots` own capabilities or do I have to do the processing outside `gnuplot` via scrips?

---

> You don't show how your exact data structure looks like, - theozh

This files are rather large. I placed an example here:
http://www.filedropper.com/log-pv-20190607-20190811 (300kB)

I'm specially interested in column 4 (`DC1 P`) and 9 (`DC2 P`).
Column 1 (`Zeit`) holds the unix timestamp.

The final goal is separate graphs (colors) for `DC1 P`  and  `DC2 P`, but that's a different question... ;o)

Comment: thanks for the addition. I don't need the whole file, just the structure and maybe a few example lines.... now I see you were mentioning CSV in the title.

Comment: @theozh I think "a few examples" would be hard to arrange to cover the same minutes of day on different days which is essential to my question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Update/Revision**:
After revisiting this answer, I guess it is time for a clean up and simpler and extended solution. After some iterations and clarifications and after OP provided some data (although, the link is not valid anymore), I came up with some suggestions, which can be improved.*

You can do all in gnuplot, no need for external tools!

The original request to plot the maximum values from several days is easy if you use the plotting style `with boxes`. But this is basically only a graphical solution. In that case is was apparently sufficient. However, if you are interested in the maximum values as numbers it is a little bit more effort.

gnuplot has the option `smooth unique` and `smooth frequency` (check `help smooth`). With this you can easily get the average and sum, respectively, but there is no `smooth max` or `smooth min`. As @meuh suggested, you can get maximum or mimimum with arrays, which are available since gnuplot 5.2.0

**Script:** (Requires gnuplot>=5.2.0)

```
### plot time data modulo 24h avg/sum/min/max
reset session

FILE = 'log-pv-20190607-20190811.csv'

set datafile separator comma
HeaderCount = 7
myTimeFmt   = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"

StartTime = ''
EndTime   = ''
# if you don't define start/end time it will be taken automatically
if (StartTime eq '' || EndTime eq '') {
    stats FILE u 1 skip HeaderCount nooutput
    StartTime = (StartTime eq '' ? STATS_min : strptime(myTimeFmt,StartTime))
    EndTime   = (EndTime   eq '' ? STATS_max : strptime(myTimeFmt,EndTime))
}

Modulo24Hours(t) = (t>=StartTime && t<=EndTime) ? (int(t)%86400) : NaN
set key noautotitle

set multiplot layout 3,2

    set title "All data" offset 0,-0.5
    set format x "%d.%m." timedate
    set grid x,y
    set yrange [0:]
    myHeight = 1./3*1.1
    set size 1.0,myHeight
    plot FILE u 1:4:(tm_mday($1)) skip HeaderCount w l lc var
    set multiplot next

    set title "Data per 24 hours"
    set format x "%H:%M" timedate
    set xtics 3600*6
    set size 0.5,myHeight
    plot FILE u (Modulo24Hours($1)):4:(tm_mday($1)) skip HeaderCount w l lc var

    set title "Average"
    set size 0.5,myHeight
    plot FILE u (int(Modulo24Hours($1))):4 skip HeaderCount smooth unique w l lc "web-green"

    set title "Sum"
    set size 0.5,myHeight
    plot FILE u (int(Modulo24Hours($1))):4 skip HeaderCount smooth freq w l

    set title "Min/Max"
    set size 0.5,myHeight
    N = 24*60/5
    SecPerDay = 3600*24
    array Min[N]
    array Max[N]
    do for [i=1:N] { Min[i]=NaN; Max[i]=0 }  # initialize arrays
    stats FILE u (idx=(int($1)%SecPerDay)/300+1, $4>Max[idx] ? Max[idx]=$4:0, \
          Min[idx]!=Min[idx] ? Min[idx]=$4 : $4<Min[idx] ? Min[idx]=$4:0 ) skip HeaderCount nooutput

    plot Min u ($1*300):2 w l lc "web-blue", \
         Max u ($1*300):2 w l lc "red"

unset multiplot
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this looks quite close to what I want except that I want only one curve consisting of the max value for the particular 5 Minute interval over all days, likewise setting all graphs to the same color and filling it.

Comment: Well, the update really looks like my desired solution. The only open issue is how to replace the *data* section with the real values from my csv file.

Comment: simply, skip the test data section and in the plot command just do `plot 'YourFile.dat' u ... `

Comment: when I use my real data (starting at august 8th covering 6 days) I get a graph over 36 hours instead of 24.

Comment: ah, ok, this is because you have half a day data before August 8th, modulo will give negative numbers. I'll adapt the code.

Comment: Thanks again for your effort! But an even better solution would take *start* and *end* from the file so that we don't have to enter it...

Comment: of course, can also be done. I will modify the code. I thought you want to manually set a certain window of several days.

Comment: Your welcome! I guess we're done?! An acceptable solution? Now it should be easy to also plot column 9 in the same way with different color.

Answer (score 1):

From gnuplot 5.2 you could use the new **array** datatype to calculate a maximum value for each 5 minute slot.  I am not a gnuplot expert, so the following example needs more work, but shows the potential.

Assume data is similar to these lines, where there is a date in the format
`yyyy.mm.dd.HH:MM`, a comma and a y value:

```
2018.02.03.18:23,4
2018.02.03.19:23,7
2018.02.04.18:23,8
2018.02.05.19:23,11
```

Instead of using gnuplot's built-in time parsing, since we want to ignore the date, we create a function `fsecs` to use `substr(stringcolumn(...),12,16)` to get just the hours and minutes from data column 1, and `strptime("%H:%M",...)` to convert this to seconds:

```
set datafile separator ","
fsecs(v) = strptime("%H:%M",substr(stringcolumn(v),12,16))
```

We create an array `Max` indexed by "5 minute slot", of which there are `24*60/5` per day. It is initialised to `NaN`, not-a-number.

```
Nitems = int(24*60/5)+1
array Max[Nitems]
do for [i=1:Nitems] {
    Max[i] = NaN
}
```

We then "plot" the data file `data.csv` into a dummy table, rather than generating any output. As we go through the data we index `Max` by the data x value (column 1) converted to seconds by `fsecs(1)` and then to slot by `findex()`. This is `Max[findex(fsecs(1))]`.
We call our function `fmax()` to return the new maximum to set in the array.

```
findex(x) = int(((x)/60)/5)
fmax(a,b) = ((a>=b)?a:b)
set table $Dummy
  plot 'data.csv' using \
    (Max[findex(fsecs(1))] = fmax(Max[findex(fsecs(1))],$2)):2
unset table
```

Finally, we plot the array, which is the slot number against the value held in that slot number.

```
plot Max using 1:(Max[$1]) with points lw 2 title "max day"
```

This works for me on 5.2. You still need to label the x axes with HH:MM, and change the date parsing to fit your needs.

Comment: thanks for your answer.   
But your suggestion gives me `array index out of range` at `(Max[findex(fsecs(1))] = fmax(Max[findex(fsecs(1))],$2)):2`.

Comment: I'm not able to test anything at the moment, but you might try changing `findex()` by adding 1 to the result and perhaps boosting `Nitems` temporarily. I'm not sure what gnuplot does with an index of 0 as arrays seem to start from 1.

Answer (score 0):

For time formating, please see [Gnuplot date/time in x axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17791828/gnuplot-date-time-in-x-axis)

If you do not care about format as time, you may use the `every` command, see [gnuplot docu](http://www.gnuplot.info/docs_4.2/node121.html), but that does not take a maximum or something.

For the maximum value over a given time interval I suggest an `awk` script, see e.g. https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/207287/297901