# gnuplot with time in x axis

Tags: datetime, format, gnuplot

I have a question related to an old post [Gnuplot date/time in x axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17791828/gnuplot-date-time-in-x-axis).

My file is similar. I have a csv data file I want to plot that was taken over multiple days. I am using a date/time format '%b %d %Y %H:%M:%S' but want to plot all of the data for just 24 hr time spans, i.e. data per time of day.

Any suggestions for how to approach this (without changing my csv format). A way to create a value by subtracting '%b %d %Y' from '%b %d %Y %H:%M:%S' perhaps?

I've only worked with gnuplot for a couple days and am still in the dark ages regarding its syntax. Thanks

Comment: Does the answer solve your problem? Any kind of response would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question you want to plot some time data where you basically want to plot it as a function of the time of the day. If the date itself is not important for you, I mean e.g. coloring or labeling of the day, then just ignore the day and set your time format `"%H:%M:%S"` starting from column 4.

**Code:**

```
### plot 
reset session

# example data
$Data <<EOD
Jan 27 2020 00:13:00   1.12
Jan 27 2020 12:22:00   2.23
Jan 27 2020 17:45:00   3.34
Jan 28 2020 01:13:00   1.23
Jan 28 2020 10:24:00   2.34
Jan 28 2020 20:35:00   3.45
Jan 29 2020 02:12:00   1.34
Jan 29 2020 13:23:00   2.45
Jan 29 2020 22:34:00   3.56
EOD

myTimeFmt = "%H:%M:%S"
set format x "%H:%M" time

plot $Data u (timecolumn(4,myTimeFmt)):5 w p pt 7 lw 2 lc rgb "red" notitle
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]